# Use data frame column names and values to name rows

Tags: r, dataframe, names

I have a data frame of different combinations that represent whether a marker is present `1` or not `0`

```
combinations_df <- expand.grid(
marker_a = c(0, 1), 
marker_b = c(0, 1), 
marker_c = c(0, 1), 
marker_d = c(0, 1)
)

   marker_a marker_b marker_c marker_d
1         0        0        0        0
2         1        0        0        0
3         0        1        0        0
4         1        1        0        0
5         0        0        1        0
6         1        0        1        0
7         0        1        1        0
8         1        1        1        0
9         0        0        0        1
10        1        0        0        1
11        0        1        0        1
12        1        1        0        1
13        0        0        1        1
14        1        0        1        1
15        0        1        1        1
16        1        1        1        1
```

I'm trying to create a vector to assign row names using each column, along with its value.

Example output:

```
                                                    marker_a marker_b marker_c marker_d
marker_a_0-marker_b_0-marker_c_0-marker_d_0         0        0        0        0
marker_a_1-marker_b_0-marker_c_0-marker_d_0         1        0        0        0
...
```

Comment: Are you looking for `apply(combinations_df, 1, function(x) paste0(names(x), "_", x, collapse = "-"))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
apply(combinations_df,
      MARGIN = 1,
      FUN = function(x) {
                            paste0(c(rbind(colnames(combinations_df), x)),
                                   collapse = "-")
                        }
      )
```

Comment: I'm still relatively new to R. Does this mean that apply() takes data frames as lists?

Comment: You can read about the `apply` function by typing `?apply` in the R console. It works in arrays and matrices, including data frames. I'm not sure what you mean by "takes them as lists" - if you're new to R it will be very helpful to read up on data structures in R.